# How to configure SMTP in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation on Windows 7?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, email, visual-web-part, smtp, development-enviroment

I am having the functionality to send email from custom WebPart(C#) using configured SMTP on SharePoint 2010. Wherein my development environment, having Windows 7 OS configured with SharePoint 2010 foundation. But don't know how to configure SMTP for SharePoint in this environment. I found links but for Server machine not for Windows 7 and Foundation environment.Further need to send mail using SPUtility.

Any help will be important guideline for me.

Comment: any luck for me

Comment: Seems nobody know about this :(